# Get objects in scope in the order they're defined

Tags: python

I have a factory function that defines several classes and returns them in a list. Is it possible to obtain such a list where the classes appear in the order in which they're defined?

The following factory uses `locals()` to get classes defined in its scope, but `locals()` returns a dictionary, so there isn't a definite ordering.

```
import inspect

def factory() :
    class Base(object):
        pass

    class A(Base):
        pass

    class B(Base):
        pass

    class C(Base):
        pass

    local_classes = [obj for obj in locals().values() if inspect.isclass(obj)]
    return [cls for cls in local_classes if issubclass(cls, Base)]

factory()
# [<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>]
```

The desired output would be

```
# [<class '__main__.Base'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>]
```

Comment: No, not without introspecting the source code and guessing the order from that. Why do you need to have a specific order?

Comment: The classes model components of a system in which order is important, and I'd rather not have to specify the position of each component in the class definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this problem a couple of times. My solution generally uses a class decorator to explicitly add each class to the factory.

I generally use instances of a factory class as the factory. However if you case a simple factory class derived from list may suffice to achieve your goal:

```
class Factory (list):
    def append(self, cls):
        super(Factory, self).append(cls)
        return cls

factory = Factory()

@factory.append
class Base (object):
    pass

@factory.append
class A (Base):
    pass

@factory.append
class B (Base):
    pass
print factory
```

Running this yields:

```
[<class '__main__.Base'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>]
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising. Care to include a small example?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde I added an example of a simple factory for you.